# Since my power supply doesn’t provide an 8 pin cable to connect it to my GPU, then what should I connect to my GPU?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu, pci-express

I replaced this graphic card:

[image: Old GPU]

With this [Asus Dual GeForce RTX™ 3060](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Graphics-Cards/Dual/DUAL-RTX3060-12G/):

[image: New GPU]

And this GPU needs 8 pins but my power supply has these. Since my power supply does not provide 8 pin, to connect it to my GPU, then what should I connect to my GPU?

Molex and SATA power connectors:

[image: Various Molex and SATA power connectors.]

Overview of inside PC:

[image: Overview of inside PC.]

Comment: You should connect the new power supply you're about to buy. Your old one is almost certainly not powerful enough to drive a decent GPU - so even tough you probably could find an adapter to make one fit into the other, it'll just shut down as soon as the load gets too high.

Comment: To add to the comment by brhans, I can't tell which model of video card that is, but an RTX 3050 can draw in excess of 130 W, and the recommended PSU power for *that* model would be a minimum of 400 W, which is substantially more than what I can see of the PSU in the photo. Check the documentation for your card.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  It's RTX 3060, is it OK to buy a 570 W PSU?

Comment: @avdaad What does it say in the manufacturer's documentation for the graphics card? If you need help locating that data, give us a link to the card's web page.

Comment: @AndrewMorton https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Graphics-Cards/Dual/DUAL-RTX3060-12G/

Comment: @avdaad To find the recommended PSU rating, you need to go to the Support link (not the one at the top of the page), then choose the "Manual & Document" tab, and find the "RECOMMENDED PSU TABLE" section. Yes, a 570 W PSU should be OK. (We don't do actual product recommendations here, in case that was your next query, but bear in mind that if something seems too good to be true, it probably is, and looking at reviews of a PSU is a good idea before purchase.)

Answer (score 7):

Your main problem, even if your existing power supply can theoretically send enough power, is that 6-pin cables are limited to 75W, whereas 8-pin can send 150W. The PCI rail can also send 75W.

The 7th & 8th pins provide an additional ground & a sensor to let the system know it is dealing with 8 pins, not 6. The extra pins themselves do not provide this extra power.

So, whatever your card, it can pull a theoretical maximum of only 150W, rather than the 225 it *may* need.
Chances are, if it needed less than 150, it would only have a 6-pin - but you really need to check the card's spec.

The image of the PSU's spec plate would be further evidence that the PSU itself is nowhere near powerful enough to handle a 225W card. The 12v rail is only 180W [this is between *all* devices].

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### You need a new PSU that can handle the new GPU’s power requirements.

Your current PSU can provide up to about 250W of power, and only 180W of that power can be delivered through the 12V rail (or rails).

This graphics card will need between 150W and 225W of power from the 12V rail. The upper limit is the sum of power provided by the PCI-e slot (75W) and through the 8-pin connector (150W). The lower limit is deduced: if 150W would be sufficient, the card would use a 6-pin connector.

In the most optimistic scenario, you have only 30W of headroom on the 12V rail, which is the most important rail in a modern PC. That's definitely not enough.

In the realistic scenario, this PSU will either:

1. Cut the power under high load, or
2. Operate out of its designed power capabilities with terrible efficiency, or
3. Will get damaged, possibly taking more parts with it.

In the pessimistic scenario, this PSU has two or more 12V rails which can provide 180W in total, but up to 90W (or less) each.

Answer (score -3):

EDIT: Yes l, u need new PSU.

For those with enough PSU Wattage:

I've got same 3060, it has 170W TDP.
In my case,  I've got Dell Precision 7520, trying to connect it as eGPU thru m.2 -> PCI-E x16 riser.

Connecting it to 400W PSU, Which has 24pin, 4 pin, 6 pin, some SATA and Molexes.

PCI-E can provide 75W. 8 PIN can provide 150W. This card has **RED LED** near 8pin if you "put there/not put there any" wrong cable.

There ARE reductions to 8 pin on market. Found (IMHO as old Dells power source replacement):
[https://www.amazon.com/COMeap-Adapter-Compatible-Optiplex-Precision/dp/B06XGWRTHC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XGWRTHC)

Then this one from 2 molexes!
https://www.czc.cz/akasa-redukce-napajeni-2x4pin-molex-power-5-25-na-1xpciexp/35837/produkt

Plus my case specific:

I have two risers, I am not able to make work this one:
https://m.aliexpress.com/item/1005004833386620.html I see GPU just sometimes in Dell Diagnostics tool.

So I ordered m.2 to USB and will connect this riser, which I bought accidentally:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B07VPJL68Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VPJL68Z)

And will try using 24+4 pin to 8 pin first riser as reduction.
And 2molex to 8 pin reduction.

Will let you know about the results + power benchmarks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your situation is completely different - you have a PSU capable of delivering enough power for this card. OP doesn't. No amount of adapters will make up for the fact that this PSU simply can't deliver enough power for this GPU and the rest of the PC.

Comment: True, my fault. But will leave the answer here if someone will be looking for it. Missed OP PSU specs