# How can I tell if my new PSU 570W?

Tags: power-supply, battery

I bought a new PSU, and I don't know if it is 570W.

Box 1
[image: Box 1]

Box 2
[image: Box 2]

PSU
[image: PSU]

And this is my old PSU.

[image: Old PSU]

So I don't know whether my new PSU is 570W or 156W, and I do not know whether my new PSU has higher wattage or the old one.

Is my new PSU 570W?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you not know the specs when you placed the order? Brand and part number would help.

Comment: If I add up all the Volts x Amps (=power) it it does not add up to 570 Watts. The box (first photo) says 230 Watts.

Comment: Were you expecting this PSU to be 570 Watts? The only 570 I see here is in the model number TP 570.

Comment: **Do not buy cheap PSUs.** They are ticking timebombs and they will take other components with them. You've just bought a very nice graphics card and you don't want a crappy PSU to destroy it.

Comment: [Previous question for context](https://superuser.com/q/1733360/194694).

Answer (score 4):

It is neither 570W nor 156W.

Your new powersupply is model number TP 570.  It is advertised as a 230W power supply.  Its maximum power output is the sum of the wattages in the final picture, which is 230.9W.  The 156W you are looking at is the portion of the total power output dedicated to the +12V lines.  Power supplies have to have separate hardware for all of the different voltages they provide, so you cannot have the full 230W on either +12V or +5V lines.  You have to account for all lines before it adds up to 230W.

Your current power supply is 254.5W, so it is more powerful than the new power supply by 23.6W.

Comment: Needles to say both the new and the old aren't sufficient for a Geforce RTXxxxx